# Atomic updates synchronization across a network of computers

Tags: networking, synchronization

Here is my problem in bullet points (I want to make it as clear as possible):

- I have a set of computers, connected in a peer to peer fashion, so there is no central server.
- Each computer can sometimes (but not really often, uptime should be around 0.98) go offline. Moreover, connections can sometimes be lost, or two nodes might not be able to connect for some reason. But most of the times the connections will work and will be fairly stable.
- Each of these computers keeps a copy of a stack of updates. Updates are numbered in a progressive order.
- At any point in time, an external user can connect to any of the computers in the network and release a (signed, so the update is verifiable across the network) update.
- The update should then be dispatched across the network, and added to the update stack of each computer.

So far so good. I know it is reasonably simple to do this:

- Updates are dispatched across the connections that the computers in the network have established.
- If at some point a computer goes offline, when it comes back online the fact that the updates are ordered and numbered will allow it to synchronize again with the network.

Now, my problem comes when there is more than one user. What happens if **two** users simultaneously try to release two different updates, connecting to two different computers in the network?

- If they just distribute the updates, some nodes will have one update and some others will have another different update in their stacks, so I have lost coherence.
- If I implement some form of locking mechanism, where before releasing an update I try to lock all the nodes, I can incur in all sorts of starvation-related problems.
- I thought about choosing a computer as master and make all the users connect to that computer, but then how do I get to choose which one is the master? The following problems appear:

  - How do I choose the master?
  - That should also be dynamical. What happens if the master goes offline?
  - Because of possibly faulty connections, not all the nodes will see a node online even if it is: on very rare occasions, it might happen that the master computer, which is online and can connect to all the other computers, will be seen as offline by one of them. What happens then?

Is there some known strategy to address this kind of issue? I bet there is. I tried looking online but I didn't really know how to phrase what I was looking for.

Comment: Something else might be useful- [Conflict-free replicated data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type). Many implementations on [github](https://github.com/search?q=crdt)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is incomplete and unfortunately vague, as I'm still trying to understand the papers linked here. But I wanted to post what I found so far.

There seem to be 2 main approaches to synchronizing a decentralized data replication system.

1. Pessimistic

Atomicity and locks fall under the category of "pessimistic" algorithms, blocking access by all other users while any one user is publishing an update.

This approach is vulnerable to deadlocks and/or starvation issues as you mentioned.

2. Optimistic

> In contrast, optimistic algorithms let data be read or written without
>   *a priori* synchronization, based on the "optimistic" assumption that problems will occur only rarely, if at all. Updates are propagated in
>   the background, and occasional conflicts are fixed after they happen.

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/739/Spring2004/Papers/optimistic-survey.pdf

According to Wikipedia, [version vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_vector) are the "main" data structure used for optimistic replication systems. However, as you noted there's an obvious concurrency problem in a decentralized context.

*"What happens if two users simultaneously try to release two different updates, connecting to two different computers in the network?"*

As Brent Hoon Kang [notes](https://oceanstore.cs.berkeley.edu/publications/papers/pdf/hh_icdcs03_kang.pdf):

> ... it is extremely rare that different users (or sites) make an update at
>   the same time. However, such rare events do happen in practice, and
>   their consequence is prohibitive: An update may be completely lost by
>   different versions having the same id. Indeed, **such an occurrence is
>   present in the CVS logs of sourceforge.net**

From Hoon's paper, apparently a way to "fix" this is by prefixing version IDs with the originating node ID and local timestamp. Then as updates are "propagated" (something I haven't grasped yet), nodes can recognize when versions are different in spite of identical version IDs, merge them, and create a new version to propagate (if I understand correctly).

However assigning unique IDs becomes slow and complicated as the number of nodes increases.

> If the sites are introduced through linear chaining (e.g., A
>   introduces B, B introduces C, C introduces D, and so on), the total
>   size of all site names could grow quadratically in terms of number of
>   sites.

There are other problems with version vectors.

[Hash histories](https://oceanstore.cs.berkeley.edu/publications/papers/pdf/hh_icdcs03_kang.pdf) offer an alternative way to do optimistic replication.

With HH's, node IDs are not required, and nodes can join or disappear at any time. Data synchronization across the network also converges faster than VV's, for a reason (described in the paper) that was over my head.

Hashing involves some probability of version collision, but AFAIU modern hashes can make this [negligible](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46062/97720) in practice.

Hoon's full thesis (related):
https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2004/CSD-04-1351.pdf

Poster summary:
http://roc.cs.berkeley.edu/retreats/summer_02/posters/hoon_poster.pdf

Since the source code link is down, I'm a little lost on some details, but I will update this answer with pseudocode when I figure it out. I apologize if I misread your question or if this isn't helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! I really appreciate the help!